# Java .jar executable not opening (on double click)

Tags: java, jar, file-association

I wrote a little command-line game that has 5 classes: the main class "DiaDia.class", and the others "Partita.class", "Comando.class", "Stanza.class", "Attrezzo.class".
Then i created a diadiamanifest.txt file so:

```
Main-Class: DiaDia
```

ending file with a new line.
I tried to make a DiaDia.jar file with 2 different commands:

```
jar cvfm DiaDia.jar diadiamanifest.txt DiaDia.class Partita.class Comando.class Stanza.class Attrezzo.class


jar cvfe DiaDia.jar DiaDia DiaDia.class Partita.class Comando.class Stanza.class Attrezzo.class
```

In both cases the generated DiaDia.jar file runs well with the command:

```
java -jar DiaDia.jar
```

but does nothing with a double click on it. 
I set properly the file association of .jar extension to

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
```

I run Windows 7 Home Premium x64, with jre7 update 76 and jdk1.7.0_76.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wrote a little command-line game

That's the problem then.

`javaw.exe` is designed to run GUI applications - it doesn't allocate a console. If you change the file association for `.jar` to run `java.exe` instead, it will launch a console and your app will run. On the other hand, anything *else* that's designed to run as a launchable jar file - most of which *will* have GUIs - will end up launching a console even if you don't want one.

Alternatively, change your game to not need a console, or just run it from a command line using `java -jar ...` which, as you've already said, works fine.